# Cannot connect to Postgres server when using latest version of Postgresql psql client tool

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, psql

When I have the latest version of Postgresql (version 12) installed through brew and try to query a cloud hosted database using psql from the zsh shell, I receive the following error: `psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

When I use postgresql version 11, I can query the database.

Other developers on my team can query the same database using the latest version of Postgresql (version 12).

Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Comment: What options are you giving to each version of psql?

Comment: It could be that your v12 client is built with `/tmp` as the default socket directory, but the v11 client isn't. Run `SHOW unix_socket_directories;` while connected to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the connection problem by uninstalling all brew packages, uninstalling brew, reinstalling brew and then reinstalling all the packages including postgresql version 12. After this, I could connect to the databases.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're connecting differently using v12 vs v11 (different shell, different host, different install method, something?) but without knowing the full connection command and/or environment info, this would be difficult to troubleshoot. Since your coworkers can connect with v12, it's not an issue with that. Since you really need more of a support forum, I'd probably recommend taking this question to the postgres slack or postgres mailing lists.